# New Instance Creates A New /CFIDE Mapping

Tags: coldfusion, instance, jrun

I've created a new instance of ColdFusion and for whatever reason it has a mapping for /CFIDE pointing at:

```
C:\JRun4\servers\{instance}\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\CFIDE
```

Even though my default instance has:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\CFIDE
```

I'd rather keep it pointing at the CFIDE under Apache, but I'm unable to edit the mapping.  If I manually change it in neo-runtime.xml it gets automagically switched back to the WAR location when I restart the instance.

Please, no suggestions to just rely on an Apache virtual directory.  While this would work for scripts, etc it doesn't truly solve the problem.  If I wanted to use the Admin API or even create Admin extensions I'd be worrying about 2 separate CFIDE directories.

Comment: Just to clarify: you edit the file, and CF actually re-writes the file, reverting it back?  Which version of CF?  Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm seeing Adam.  CF 9.0.1 with CHF 2.  I think this used to work - I'm wondering if it is a "security feature" (being unable to edit the neo-xxx.xml).  Can you test on CF 10?

Comment: And you are editing the mapping within the instance you created right? Sometimes I get my instances crossed :)

Comment: Mark - Yep.  It's the only instance (besides default) on this machine right now.

Comment: Yeah Todd, I'll test on both CF9.0.1 & CF10 this evening (+12h from now).  I'll report back.

Comment: Todd, I just tested on CF901, and I can relocate the CFIDE dir just fine.  This is on Win Server 2k3, 32-bit.  Perhaps the problem is a vagary of your rig?

Comment: CF10 is a different story.  Tomcat won't serve CFM files outside the webroot dir, so this is not so possible on CF10.  One would need to use the directory junction approach I mentioned in my "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd, if you can't resolve your particular issue (as per comments directly against your initial question), you could perhaps just a directory junction instead: get rid of the new instance's CFIDE dir completely, and create a junction at that location pointing to the one you wish to share between instances.

This is a slight hack, but if all else fails it'll work.

But to be clear: I do *not* have the problem you are having on CF9.0.1: what you're trying to do should work. So I think there's something else afoot here which probably needs addressing.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Given that it's a dev setup I think I'm just going to leave it as is for now but I've marked this answer as accepted.